# How to avoid continuous notification when notification is clicked

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, receiver

I want to send notification by BroadcastReceiver. Notification sent by AlarmReceiver but again sent notification when i clicked the notification. The same thing happens again, again and again like endless loop

Here is my `AlarmReceiver.java`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    // This intent is fired when notification is clicked
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

    // Notifcation notify sound
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Large icon appears on the left of the notification
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    // Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
    builder.setContentTitle("Have a good weekend");

    //Notification click after clear notification
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    //Set notification sound
    builder.setSound(alarmSound);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    }
}
```

and `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAlarm();
}

private void setAlarm(){
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,53);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: hi @emrekose26, you have face this problem because you set set Alarm()  
in On create activity and when you received notification and click on notification then MainActivity is open. so, again call setAlarm() give notification again.

Answer (score 0):

As on click on notification it open `MainActivity` and in `onCreate` method of this activity you are calling `setAlarm()` . So on click of notification `onCreate` method is invoked  then `setAlarm()` is invoked , this again set Alarm and build notification.

**Do following changes**

call `setAlarm()` `onClick` of a button, so that it is not invoked automatically `onCreate` of activity.

**If you want to send notification automatically**

change the intent of `notification`

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

As of now you are using intent to open `ManinActivity` on click of notification.

Change `Intent` to

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
```

OtherActivity is the activity which does not `setAlarm()` or build `notification` in `onCreate` method.

**Alternative Method**

Use `sharedPreferences` to check whether the notification is build once or not.
if build once then don't call `setAlarm()`

Comment: notification should send automaticly therefore i can't use `onClick`

Comment: @emrekose26 I have edited my answer. Let me know for any problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer but other activity shouldn't open when notification clicked.

Comment: @emrekose26 Is your `MainActivity` is launcher activity?

Comment: @emrekose26 what you want to do on click of the notification?

Comment: i want to start to application.

Comment: Probably works. I'll try your alternative method and let you know.

Comment: @emrekose26 okay. Let me know for any problem